# Cannot install nuget package - package not found error

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

I am unable to install a package pushed to company source. In package manager I see the correct most up-to-date version but when I try to install it I get an error:

Package 'xxxx' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'https://company/nuget/v2/index.json,https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.

The situation is strange because my colleagues are capable of installing this very package for the same project on their machines on the same version of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the error by removing ".vs" folder from the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours struggle I found solution here
https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/docs/uwp/online-getting-started/config-nugetpackage.html

Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources. > Click add button and add following one by one

nuget.org
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

GrapeCity
http://nuget.grapecity.com/nuget
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Our problem was that we had our own libraries published on NuGet.org and in a local repository. Among these, they did not match, but the first domain of the namespace did coincide. This forced us to have Packages sources mappings configured. This gave us numerous problems, so we decided to use a different namespace for the libraries that were used in NuGet and in the local repository. We also removed from the NuGet.org index those that were already published. By doing this, clearing the package manager's cache, and removing the package sources, everything was fixed.